# Control some code to be executed once in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I can't control how to make  to execute some code once using mpi

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define N 10
#define ITERS 1
// N and ITERS might be input arguments

double **A;
int times = 0;

void initialize (double **A)
{
  int i,j;

  for(i =0; i < N+2 ; i++){
    for(j =0; j < N+2 ; j++){
      if(i== 0 || j == 0 || i == (N+1) || j == (N +1) )
      A[i][j] = 0.0;
      else
      A[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  int MyProc, size,tag=1;
  char msg='A', msg_recpt;
  MPI_Status status;
  double **received_array;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyProc);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  printf("Process # %d started \n", MyProc);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  int i;
  /******Make it once*******/
  if(times == 0){
    printf("One time\n");
    A = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double *));

    for (i=0; i<N+2; i++) {
      A[i] = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double));
    }
    initialize(A);
    times ++;
  }
  /*************/


    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I've tried with `times` variable as a flag but *the make it once* section  it's executed once per process...everethig I've tried it's executed once per process ,I don't know what to try, I can't make it using the rank of teh process because I need the first procees to arrive executes the once section.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have the rank 0 process then have the other processes wait at a Barrier?  I'm not familiar enough with the advanced parts of MPI to say you can't do what your asking, but I don't think you can do it without a large amount of extra communication.

Comment: Although, if everything is on one computer, you might be able to use OpenMP's `@omp single` pragma

Comment: in MPI, each process has its own memory space, which means each process has its own *version* of `times`. you can simply `if (0 == MyProc) do_something_once()`. If you want one task initialize `A` for everyone, you will have to `MPI_Bcast()` after the initialization.

Comment: My problem is that I neet to do something once to be used by all the processes,I'm not sure how to meake the proceses work with an array